# Cryptic Family Reunion: Numbers (fan-made)

Tags: knowledge, cryptic-clues

The answers to the following cryptic clues all belong to a certain group. The definition part of each clue has been replaced by a number. Another number, hidden in the puzzle, gives a hint toward figuring out the identity of the group.

The checkmark is given to the first answer to explain the **wordplay** to each clue, the identity of the **group**, and the meaning of the selected **numbers**.

1. New mule placed in legendary frame for twenty (6)
2. "Italian river, almost azure... amazing", describes ten (6)
3. Nineteen lords mint afresh (9)
4. Empire in Azerbaijan partially turning toward the west for thirty-three (6)
5. Thirty-one's hotel covered in pelt (4)
6. Engineer nods near nine (8)
7. Eleven's an Argentinian footballer meeting constant resistance (7)
8. Ninety-nine is gloomy, about to zap Korean leaders (7)
9. Eccentric monk, see twenty-seven (7)
10. In retrospect, bother about Sumerian city being seventeen (5)
11. Greek breakfast item for twenty-one (5)
12. Hot drink picked up for seven (6)
13. Thirteen terrorized linesman (8)
14. Yankee supporting China's paramount leader, middle-aged couple and twenty-two (5)
15. Fifteen to scam a singer (8)
16. Out loud, close to the ground is four (4)
17. Upset lingo of two (7)
18. Run the bananas to twelve (6)
19. After 1250, the Spanish territory shows twenty-four (10)
20. A thousand facing sticky substance coming up to thirty-five (4)
21. Auditor's colour properties describe sixteen (6)
22. A giant slayer's working for twenty-nine (7)

Comment: Also check out [other "cryptic family reunion" puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A69217+cryptic+family+reunion) by @JeremyDover!

Comment: Finally I get to DO one :-) Thanks @jafe!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answers:

> `L_(UMLE*)_Y`
>  `PO+UZAR(-e)*`
>  `LINDSTROM*`
>  `_ZANIER_<`
>  `FU(H)R`
>  `ANDERSON*`
>  `MESSI+E+R`
>  `GRE(T_ Z_ K_)Y`
>  `SEMENKO*`
>  `K(UR)RI<`
>  `GR+EGG`
>  `COFFEY ("coffee")`
>  `LINSEMAN*`
>  `HU+_DD_+Y`
>  `CON+A+CHER`
>  `LOWE ("low")`
>  `FOGOLIN*`
>  `HUNTER*`
>  `MCCL+EL+LAND`
>  `M+OOG<`
>  `HUGHES ("hues")`
>  `JACK'S ON`

The connection:

> These are all players from the Edmonton Oilers, specifically on the 1984 team (as hinted by the first letters of each clue). The numbers replacing definitions are the players' jersey numbers.

Comment: #20's wrong, but that's because I managed to put the wrong number in the clue... It's supposed to be 35, not 34. Sorry about that!

Comment: @jafe Should #4 be 30 instead of 33 too?

Comment: You nipped me by a minute and a clue — nice solve! #4 switched numbers halfway through that season, I think — [33 is correct as of this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/1984_Stanley_Cup_Finals)